# Is there any way to automatically maintain a "latest" version folder with github?

Tags: windows, git, github, github-for-windows

I have a github repo that lists hundreds of "name" folders. In each of the "name" folders I have "version" folders for each version of the content.

example:

```
    nameFolder1 -> 0.1 -> Multiple files for version 0.1
                -> 0.2 -> Multiple files for version 0.2
    nameFolder2
    ...
```

What I want is in each of the "name" folders to have a "latest" folder which will always have the files of the newest version.
Basically when I add a new "version" folder have it somehow create the "latest" folder if it doesnt exist and then copy there the files of the latest version. If the folder exists then just delete everything in it and paste the files from the latest version folder.

Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: stop doing folders and start doing tags

Comment: I can't, the project itself are the folders. Tags are no use

Comment: Jim, you're not thinking 4th dimensionally. A repo contains the history of all commits ever. Scrap the idea of having previous versions in folders. Convert everything to being in one folder where older versions are tags to commits sometime in the past.

Comment: That would be interesting, but if I download the master branch I still need the folders to be in the way I explained. Is this possible?

Comment: If you download the master branch you would have all the versions, just checkout the different tags. `git checkout [tag name]` boom that version is the one you are using.